# List membership in Python without "in"

Tags: python, membership

How to define a function is_member() that takes a value (i.e. a number, string, etc) x and a list of values a, and returns True if x is a member of a, False otherwise. (Note that this is exactly what the in operator does, but for the sake of the exercise I should pretend Python did not have this operator.

This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work!

```
def is_member(x, a):
   return x == a[::]
```

Comment: In real code, you'd use a `set` if you need this more than a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive solution:

```
def is_member(value, array):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return False
    return value == array[0] or is_member(value, array[1:])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks everyone for the efforts.

Comment: And now for the real question: What makes this acceptable that doesn't make the other answers acceptable? Stay tuned. Question should be tagged "quiz" ;)

Comment: Since this is tagged homework, why didn't you go further and make it something like `is_member = lambda x, y: False if len(y) == 0 else x == y[0] or is_member(x, y[1:])`.?

Comment: As someone else one said "I lump this into the gratuitous recursion category, along with recursive implementations of factorial (when iterative versions are just as good, without all the function call overhead)".

Comment: I'd just like to add that while I would never support having this code in Python (The correct answer is "use `in`"), the way I have formulated it is indeed the idiomatic way to solve this problem in a functional language. It is tail recursive, and would not cause any function call overhead. But again: Don't do this in Python.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two (**edit:** three) ways to do this:

First:

```
def is_member(array, value):
    try:
        array.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Second:

```
def is_member(array, value):
    for item in array:
        if item == value:
            return True
    return False
```

**EDIT:** Also, third:

```
def is_member(array, value):
    return array.count(value) > 0
```

Comment: second way is using 'in' operator, which is not allowed. The two others do nothing i.e 
is_member([1], [3,4,1]) return False in both cases

Comment: I thought "in" was only unallowed in direct use. Anyways, you're mixing up the arguments, it's `is_member([3, 4, 1], 1)` (note that 2nd isn't an array).

Comment: Fourth way: Similar to first only using `set(array).remove(value)` and `except KeyError:`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a generator expression (note that this `in` operator has nothing to do with the another one)

```
def is_member(x, a):
   return any(x == y for y in a)

>>> is_member(10, xrange(1000000000000000))
True
```

Comment: @Tim: as a lazy generator expression, it will break on the first match.

Comment: Yes, sorry (and +1); I had timed a similar but subtly different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply just iterate over every element in the list then:

```
def is_member(col, a):
    for i in xrange(len(col)):
        if a == col[i]: return True
    return False


>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>> is_member(a, 2)
True
>> is_member(a, 5)
False
```

Comment: Why iterate manually over `col`? `for i in col: if a==i` should do.

Comment: @Gusto: In `for i in iterable`, the `in` is not an operator. Just a keyword required by the grammer.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the "in" operator:

```
from itertools import imap
def is_member( item, array ):
    return any( imap(lambda x: x == item, array ) )
```

which will cycle through the items of the list, one at a time, and short circuit when it hits a value that is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of ways to do this, of course -- but you're a little hamstrung by the prohibition of "in" anywhere in the code. Here are a few things to try.

Variations on a theme ...

```
def is_member(item, seq):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x == item, seq)) > 0

def is_member(item, seq):
    return len(filter(lambda x: x != item, seq)) != len(seq)
```

You may have heard that asking for forgiveness is better than asking for permission ...

```
def is_member(item, seq):
    try:
        seq.index(item)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Or something a little more functional-flavored ...

```
import itertools, operator, functools
def is_member(item, seq):
    not_eq = functools.partial(operator.ne, item)
    return bool(list(itertools.dropwhile(not_eq, seq)))
```

But, since your requirements preclude the use of the looping construct which would be most reasonable, I think the experts would recommend writing your own looping framework. Something like ...

```
def loop(action, until):
    while True:
        action()
        if until():
            break

def is_member(item, seq):
    seq   = seq
    sigil = [False]

    def check():
        if seq[0] == item:
            sigil[0] = True
    def til():
        seq.remove(seq[0])
        return not len(seq)

    loop(check, til)

    return sigil[0]
```

Let us know how it goes.